# How to prevent app from creating an instance of another app during startActivityForResult?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have app A that interacts with app B. When I launched app B using `startActivityForResult`, app A creates an instance of app B. While the actual app B can still be launched manually.

Is it possible to launch app B using `startActivityForResult`, but this time brings the actual app B to foreground?

Activity declaration on App B's Manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".activities.AppBActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="intent.action.ApplicationBActivity" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

        <data
            android:host="appBHost"
            android:scheme="appBScheme" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Application A launching B.

```
Intent launchAppB = new Intent(appBCustomAction, Uri.parse(schemeAndHost));
startActivityForResult(launchAppB, LAUNCH_APP_B_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your application B's `Activity` `launchMode` which is declared in your `AndroidManifest` file. You can read more about `lauchMode` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode). In your case I suggest you to use `launchMode=singleTask`.

Comment: I tried using the launchMode singleTask and singleInstance on app B's activity. However app A is still creating an instance of app B, not launching the actual App B.

Comment: Can you post your code and your `AndroidManifest` file?